# Problem with Asymptote

Tags: asymptote

I recently install the latest version of asymptote (2.47), and now Nothing work with asymptote. On windowds 10 system, I have this messages when I want compile a file.asy open with NotePadd++:

> asy -V  prgm1.asy 
>   Process started (PID=4768) >>>
>
> 1 [main] asy (12092) C:\Program Files (x86)\Asymptote\asy.exe: *** fatal error - cygheap base mismatch detected - 0x5872410/0x5812410.
>   This problem is probably due to using incompatible versions of the cygwin DLL.
>   Search for cygwin1.dll using the Windows Start->Find/Search facility
>   and delete all but the most recent version.  The most recent version *should*
>   reside in x:\cygwin\bin, where 'x' is the drive on which you have
>   installed the cygwin distribution.  Rebooting is also suggested if you
>   are unable to find another cygwin DLL.
>
> 1 [main] asy 4768 fork: child -1 - forked process 12092 died unexpectedly, retry 0, exit code 0xC0000142, errno 11
>   C:\Program Files (x86)\Asymptote/plain_Label.asy: 321.15: runtime: fork failed: latex\scrollmode
>
> <<< Process finished (PID=4768). (Exit code 1)

Of course, before, I never use Cygwin and I have not cygwin directory on C:\ …

Who can help me to solve this problem and retrieve my use of asy.exe?

Thank a lot.
Dominque Collin.

Nota :

On command Windows, when en use the asy command I have this :

```
C:\>asy
Welcome to Asymptote version 2.47 (to view the manual, type help)
>
```

So, it's fine, but, for example, when I use this : help, 
asy crashes and give this message:

```
> help
  2 [main] asy 6100 child_info_fork::abort: C:\Program Files (x86)\Asymptote\freeglut.dll: Loaded to different address: parent(0x1C0000) != child(0x5980000)
C:\Program Files (x86)\Asymptote/plain.asy: 48.18: runtime: Cannot fork process
```

Comment: Who can help me to run asymptote on windows10 machine?